# Apache Echarts: labels,splitLine disappear in radius axis of polar bar chart

Tags: angular, echarts, ngx-echarts

Using
echarts 4.9,
ngx-echarts 4.2.2

The labels, axis lines in radial axis gets disappear some times during zoom. Also the tooltip during hover is showing differently.

[image: Incorrect chart]Incorrect chart
[image: correct chart]Correct chart

option values set,

```
   options = {
  "color": [
    "#32C5E9"
  ],
  "legend": {
    "type": "scroll",
    "orient": "vertical",
    "bottom": 0,
    "right": 0,
    "data": []
  },
  "angleAxis": {
    "show": true,
    "splitArea": {
      "show": false
    },
    "splitLine": {
      "show": true
    },
    "axisLine": {
      "show": false
    },
    "axisTick": {
      "show": false
    }
  },
  "radiusAxis": {
    "show": true,
    "type": "category",
    "data": ["Machines","Phones","Chairs","Tables", "Storage", "Binders","Accessories","Bookcases", 
     "Furnishings","Copiers","Appliances","Paper","Art","Supplies","Envelopes"],
    "z": 10,
    "splitLine": {
      "show": true
    },
    "axisLabel": {
      "rotate": 45
    }
  },
  "polar": {},
  "dataZoom": [
    {
      "show": false
    }
  ],
  "tooltip": {
    "trigger": "axis",
    "axisPointer": {
      "type": "shadow",
      "label": {
        "backgroundColor": "#6a7985"
      }
    }
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "name": "All",
      "data": ["32622.1", "31036.5", "30809.1","24476.6","21809.6","21412.5","20481.4","13835.0", "10223.8","9359.8","8369.9","6386.2","3858.1","2391.6","2109.3"],
      "type": "bar",
      "coordinateSystem": "polar",
      "barMaxWidth": 20,
      "itemStyle": {
        "shadowColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
        "shadowBlur": 5,
        "shadowOffsetX": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The same issue occurs during some times for different dataset also.